# Auto increment order number based on column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement as follow:

1. Order No should be increment based on country code (it should not have jump number on any circumstances)
   eg: 0000002 jump to 0000004
2. It should survive on multiple read replicas and race condition

I am trying to implement as below, but not sure if it does satisfy requirements and feasible on large scale. Also, i see it is a bit redundant to have an OrderNoInt column.

Hope someone can provide me a better solution.

**Approach:**
Primary Key: OrderNo

```
OrderNo    OrderNoInt  CountryCode
US0000001  1            US
US0000002  2            US
KR0000001  1            KR
KR0000002  2            KR
```

**SQL Code** (Following is SQL Server Code, but I am looking for Postgres solution)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @OrderNoInt INT
    DECLARE @OrderNo VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @OrderNoInt = MAX(OrderNoInt) + 1 
    FROM Order WITH (XLOCK)
    WHERE CountryCode = @CountryCode

    SELECT @OrderNo =  TO_CHAR(@OrderNoInt, 'fm0000000') 

    INSERT... (@OrderNo)
COMMIT
```

There will also be bulk processing in orders tables, what happen if i have 5 minutes bulk processing on the table scheduling at midnight, and at the same time there is order coming in since i am doing a lock?

Comment: That code is clearly not for Postgres. Are you sure you are using Postgres?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes i am looking for a solution to postgres, but i am using the code of sql server as example

Comment: You are looking for a gapless "sequence" generator. See e.g. [this blog post](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/gapless-sequence/). The approach with `max() + 1` is typically a bad idea.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that seems to be solving half the problem, what about i have 5 mins bulk update on that particular time when there is new order coming it. Will the new order need to wait for the bulk update to be completed?. Also, Will it work on read replicas?